# strip out digits or letters at the most right of a string

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have a file name: `kjrjh20111103-BATCH2242_20111113-091337.txt`

I only need `091337`, not the txt or the - how can I achieve that. It does not have to be 6 numbers it could be more or less but will always be after "-" and the last ones before ."doc" or ."txt"

Comment: Use a regular expression

Comment: `(\d+)\..+$` This pattern should work for you

Comment: @Ramhound, I guess they know that as it's tagged as `regex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do this with a regex, or with simple string operations. For the latter:

```
int lastDash = text.LastIndexOf('-');
string afterDash = text.Substring(lastDash + 1);
int dot = afterDash.IndexOf('.');
string data = dot == -1 ? afterDash : afterDash.Substring(0, dot);
```

*Personally* I find this easier to understand and verify than a regular expression, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I'd probably suggest parsing the filename independent of splitting out the the number from the name string - the potential for entertainment just from parsing the filename is considerable.

Answer (score 1):

```
String fileName = kjrjh20111103-BATCH2242_20111113-091337.txt;
String[] splitString = fileName.Split ( new char[] { '-', '.' } );
String Number = splitString[2];
```

Comment: number should be a string, their example `091337` would be parsed to `91337` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The Regex would be:

```
string fileName = "kjrjh20111103-BATCH2242_20111113-091337.txt";
string fileMatch = Regex.Match(fileName, "(?<=-)\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `.*-(?<num>[0-9]*).` should do the job. num capture group contains your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String fileName = "kjrjh20111103-BATCH2242_20111113-091337.txt";
        var startIndex = fileName.LastIndexOf('-') + 1;
        var length = fileName.LastIndexOf('.') - startIndex;
        var output = fileName.Substring(startIndex, length);
```